# javascript function call from Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have java script function in web not on local file. I want to call hasAccount which will return object. please help this is my javascript code:

```
function GameState() {
var n = this;
function i(e) {
    e && e()
}
n.profile = null,
n.daily = null,
n.costs = null,
n.fcmToken = null,
n.adUnitId = null,
n.boot = function(t) {
    api.trivia.boot(function(e) {
        n.profile = e.profile,
        n.daily = e.daily,
        n.costs = e.costs,
        n.adUnitId = e.ad_unit_id,
        i(t)
    })
},
n.refreshProfile = function(t) {
    api.trivia.playerProfile(function(e) {
        n.profile = e,
        i(t)
    })
},
n.refreshDaily = function(t) {
    api.trivia.daily(referrer, !1, function(e) {
        n.daily = e,
        i(t)
    })
},
n.hasAccount = function() {
    return null != n.profile.display_name
},
n.setCredits = function(e) {
    return n.profile.credits = e
},
n.setFcmToken = function(e) {
    e != n.fcmToken && (n.fcmToken = e, api.trivia.setFcmToken(e))
}
```

I want to call this function setFcmToken: Any suggestions in Swift:

```
func fetchDisplayNameInJavaScript() {
    // Call the JavaScript function with the FCM token as an argument
    let javascriptFunction = "(new GameState()).hasAccount();"
    
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptFunction) { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error evaluating JavaScript: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("JavaScript function executed successfully.")
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting error:
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.profile.display_name'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=546, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=https://qwizzers.app/static/qwizzers-app.js?v=744804868, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}

expected result should return "n.profile.display_name"